# Toggle between different language

Tags: asp.net, css

I am working on a website in asp.net , and i want to give a radio box so user can toggle between urdu and english keyboards. I need help in providing urdu keyboard in asp.net. I want to embed a urdu keyboard in the form.

Comment: Short of creating your own control Google for "JavaScript Virtual Keyboard"

Comment: Any useful link. I googled alot, but didnt found smart code :p , easy to read and implement. I could implemented the large one but later i have to maintaine it as well.

Comment: Added an answer with link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There're multiple virtual keyboard implementation, for example one with Urdu support: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17128/JavaScript-VirtualKeyboard

Comment: Thank you it is helpful. Still i was hoping for some more links